# Is the set of rational numbers of the form $\frac{a^2}{b^2}$ where $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers dense in the set of non-negative real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Consider the set $S=\left\{\frac{a^2}{b^2}:a,b\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$, which is clearly a strict subset of the non-negative rational numbers (for example $2\notin S$).
Is $S$ dense in the set of non-negative real numbers?

Comment: Sure.  Hint:  For any given $\frac nm$ take arbitrarily good rational approximations to $\sqrt n, \sqrt m$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, and in fact a much more general statement holds.

There's a general fact about topological spaces at work here: if $A$ is a dense subset of $B$ and $f: B\rightarrow B$ is continuous and surjective, then $f(A)$ is dense in $B$. *Proof: pick $b\in B$ and an open $U\ni b$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open since $f$ is continuous, hence contains an element of $A$.*

So since $\mathbb{Q}_{\ge 0}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ and $f: x\mapsto x^2$ is continuous and surjective from $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ to $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$, we have that $f(\mathbb{Q}_{\ge 0})$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$. But $f(\mathbb{Q}_{\ge 0})=S$.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible to have a reference for this?

Comment: @user52227 Not that I know of, it's a basic result in topology so I doubt it has a name. You can probably find it as a lemma or something in Munkres, though.